# random number in C#

Tags: random, number-formatting

I want display a random 4 digit number without repeating ,And I want to answer with one round in while ring, in The following code once the first round is answer and once the sixth round is answer.
i want, At least get around the rings to answer.

```
Random Number = new Random();
int Num1, Num2, Num3, Num4;
int Index = 0;
do
{
    Num1 = NUmber.Next(0, 10);
    Num2 = NUmber.Next(0, 10);
    Num3 = NUmber.Next(0, 10);
    Num4 = NUmber.Next(0, 10);
    Index++;  
} 
while (Num1==Num2||Num1==Num3||Num1==Num4||Num2==Num3||Num2==Num4||Num3==Num4);
Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}{3}",Num1,Num2,Num3,Num4);
Console.WriteLine(Index);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Please correct your grammar, it is unclear what you are asking. Is it single 4-digit number with unique digits for every loop iteration?

Answer (score 0):

If you need random 4-digit number on every iteration, where digits are unique - consider using shuffle algorithm. This way digits are never repeated in single generated number, although numbers on every iteration may repeat.

```
using System;
class App
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    int[] digits = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    var rnd = new Random();
    while (true)
    {
      int i = 0;
      Swap(digits,i, rnd.Next(i+1, digits.Length)); i++;
      Swap(digits,i, rnd.Next(i+1, digits.Length)); i++;
      Swap(digits,i, rnd.Next(i+1, digits.Length)); i++;
      Swap(digits,i, rnd.Next(i+1, digits.Length)); i++;
      Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}{3}", 
          digits[0], digits[1], digits[2], digits[3]);
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
  static void Swap(int[] digits, int i, int j)
  {
    var t = digits[i]; digits[i] = digits[j]; digits[j] = t;
  }
}
```